# How easy is it to create a YouTube to MP3 application using yt-dlp and ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, yt-dlp

I was thinking I could automate the process of downloading a video and converting it to mp3 (or other formats).
Instead of doing the process myself (which doesn't take that long and isn't too much hassle), which looks something like this:
• `yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ`
• wait for download then (find and) rename file to something simpler for next command
• `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 video.mp3`

I thought I could turn it into a simple JS (or other language) program instead, where it:

1. Asks for link and what format I want it in
2. Downloads the video
3. Renames it (not sure how easy this is)
4. Turns it into requested format
5. Opens file location

If something like this is possible, please let me know some things I should know since I've never written a windows app before, and some general guidance for how I could do this.
I apologise if questions like this aren't exactly allowed on this site, its my first time posting too.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Windows, you can write a Batch Script to do this. it might be helpful to break your question down into individual questions and try to answer them one at a time.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark this as answered. I've got far enough with this now that I (mostly) know what I'm doing.